# ssh ForceCommand vs. ProxyCommand

Tags: shell, sshd

I need to have a group of users hop through a server ('bastion') into another machine ('dest') via ssh to commit code.

Seems like my options are:

1. tell users to use `ProxyCommand` in their .ssh/config file, something like:

   `Host dest`
   `ProxyCommand ssh -q bastion nc -q0 dest 22`
2. use `ForceCommand` in the sshd config file, like

   `Match Group hopUsers`
    `ForceCommand ssh dest $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`
3. use the `command` option in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` users' file, like

   `command="ssh dest"`

The first solution is great, it works with mercual commits, etc. -- The problem is that I don't want to give my users a valid shell on the `bastion` machine. I could set their login shell to /bin/false, but this leaves a whole set of issues unattended (see [here](http://www.semicomplete.com/articles/ssh-security/)) -- unless perhaps coupled with a dedicated set of options (like noX11Forwarding) in the `sshd` config file, within a `Match` stanza.

The problem with the second and third solution is that public key authentication is 'lost', i.e. unless the client uses the `-A` option when launching ssh, the server will respond with:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: .ssh/XXXXXX
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

Hence requesting the user password. This is not acceptable.

I think there is something that can be done with `nc` in proxy mode, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be:

On the client side, in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host dest
    ProxyCommand ssh -q bastion
```

On the server side, in `sshd_config`:

```
Match Group hopUsers
        ForceCommand nc -q0 dest port
```

The users' `authorized_keys` on the server does not need any `command=`.

Now if a user tries to do anything else (e.g. launches ssh without the ProxyCommand) all they get is netcat's output

```
$ ssh user@bastion
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2
```

Thanks to the folks of #openssh on freenode.

Comment: I try to match Group and host in line, see my question as well : http://superuser.com/questions/876045/ssh-forcecommand-with-match. Did you have a solution for that as well?