# ssh ForceCommand with Match

Tags: ssh, shell

I try to setup a `ssh` server which is a kind of jumping host to other servers reachable via `ssh`. For that I use the `ForceCommand` like this:

```
Match Group g_ssh
ForceCommand nc -q0 my_internal_server 22
```

This works fine so far. But now I want to use the match also with the `Host` directive.
So my new config looks like this:

```
Match Group g_ssh Host my_internal_server
ForceCommand nc -q0 my_internal_server 22
Match Group g_ssh Host my_2_int_server
ForceCommand nc -q0 my_2_int_server
```

But this did not work. This is not working because of the not working `Host` directive.

I've also tried:

```
Match Host my_internal_Server
ForceCommand nc -q0 my_internal_server 22
```

This also did not work.

Are there any suggestions how to use the `Match` `Host` with `Group`?

Comment: Which host do you want to match to? The one the user came from, or the local host?

Comment: I want to match to the ssh destination. So the internal server the use wants to connect

Answer (score 0):

You can't match a destination host - the incoming connection would not know anything about it.

If you look at the text of my answer https://superuser.com/a/392717/19223 the first item talks about the *user* `.config` file, whilst the second item talks about the *server* `sshd_config` file.

Ultimately I would recommend using `Match Group` and making different users for each destination. Something like

```
Match Group group1 
    ForceCommand nc -q0 my_internal_server 22

Match Group group2
    ForceCommand nc -q0 my_2_int_server 22
```

Then create different users, say `user_1` belonging to `group1` and `user_2` belonging to `group2`. Then in the users' `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host internal_server_1
    ProxyCommand ssh -q server
    User user_1
Host internal_server_2
    ProxyCommand ssh -q server
    User user_2
```

This way a user can use

```
ssh internal_server_1
```

without having to care about usernames and destination hosts.

Don't forget to create user account on your main server for each user_1, user_2 account and put the right SSH key in there.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. I tried to configure this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config of the jumping host. In this config file Match Host should be allowed, mentioned in the ssh_config man page. But I did not get worked in combination with Group - as mentioned in my initial post